# How to twist material

Tags: materials

The material on the trunk of the tree looks repetitive and unnatural. I'm thinking maybe I can twist the material along the trunk so the repetitive pattern doesn't show on one side. Any idea on how I can do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Pretty useful nodegroup here: [BlenderGuru - How to Tile a Texture Without Repetition](https://youtu.be/-VgtSL5ZpYc)

Comment: Thanks! That looks really useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the UV unwrapping, it may be as easy as offsetting either X or Y coordinate by the other. A *Math > Multiply* can be used to control the strength of the shear:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I've never used converter nodes before, so took me a while to learn. I copied your nodes above. Seems to be working, but I feel the mapping is now a bit off. Can't quite put my finger on what's wrong with it, but it might be something to do with the UV unwrapping... I'll post a picture below.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hmmm... I think it might be because it's no longer a single continuous wrap.

Comment: This would be better as a comment or part of your question according to BSE rules, anyway, hard to see on the GIF, but I think there's a mirroring effect on the left side of the trunk. What probably happens is that you UV unwrapped the cylinder in a way that it has two halves residing on the same UV space, but one is flipped (hence the mirroring). And so moving the UV coordinate is moving both halves in the opposite ways. You could check using normal or sign of Y coordinate to flip the offset on one side, or unwrap the cylinder in a usual way (seams on top, bottom and one edge loop).

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll do some study on UV. Btw, I tried to put the image in the comments, but I don't know how to; drag and drop didn't work.

Comment: For comments I upload to imgur and then paste the link.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!